# Can a Jewish king abdicate?

Tags: halacha-theory, malchut-royalty

When a person is crowned as king either via anointing by an established prophet of God or by being the son of a previous king from the line of David (assuming no other siblings make a claim); can that person at any point for any reason abdicate the thrown and choose to no longer be king? Furthermore, even if it would be a sin to do so, if in fact a king did so would it be effective halachically, meaning after the fact would he still need to be treated as king even after abdication?

Comment: In II Kings 15:5, the king is diseased so he goes off to live in relative isolation, leaving his son running the day-to-day kingdom. So that was a delegation of duties, not a full abdication; but probably the closest precedent of which I'm aware.

Comment: I believe the Gemara says that when David was fleeing Avshalom he had the halachos of a commoner as he had lost authority, so we see that to some degree that it can be effective

Comment: @AKA source for that?

Comment: רב חונא אמר כל אותן ששה חדשי' שהיה דוד בורח מפני אבשלום בנו בשעירה היה מתכפר כהדיוט

Comment: @rikitikitembo ירושלמי ראש השנה דף ב ב